# Delineate twice through a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sparse pandas DataFrame/Series with values that look like variations of `"AB1234:12, CD5678:34, EF3456:56"`. Something to the effect of

```
"AB1234:12, CD5678:34, EF3456:56"
"AB1234:12, CD5678:34"
NaN
"GH5678:34, EF3456:56"
"OH56:34"
```

Which I'd like to convert into

```
["AB1234","CD5678", "EF3456"]
["AB1234","CD5678"]
NaN
["GH5678","EF3456"]
["OH56"]
```

This kind of "double delineation" has been proving difficult. I know we can `A = df["columnName"].str.split(",")` however I've run across a couple of problems including that `.split(", ")` doesnt seem to work and '.split(",")' leaves whitespace. Also, that iterating through the generated `A` and splitting seems to be interpreting my new lists as 'floats'. Although that last one might be a technical difficulty with ipython - I'm trying to work out that problem as well.

Is there a way to delineate on two types of separators - instead of just one? If not, how do you perform the loop to iterate over the inner list?

> //Edit: changed the apostrophes to commas - that was just my dyslexia
>   kicking in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly had it, note you can use a regular expression to split more generally:

```
In [11]: s2
Out[11]:
0    AB1234:12, CD5678:34, EF3456:56
1               AB1234:12, CD5678:34
2                                NaN
3               GH5678:34, EF3456:56
4                            OH56:34
dtype: object

In [12]: s2.str.split(", '")
Out[12]:
0    [AB1234:12, CD5678:34, EF3456:56]
1               [AB1234:12, CD5678:34]
2                                  NaN
3               [GH5678:34, EF3456:56]
4                            [OH56:34]
dtype: object

In [13]: s2.str.split("\s*,\s*'")
Out[13]:
0    [AB1234:12, CD5678:34, EF3456:56]
1               [AB1234:12, CD5678:34]
2                                  NaN
3               [GH5678:34, EF3456:56]
4                            [OH56:34]
dtype: object
```

*Where this removes any spaces before or after a comma.*

Comment: Prompted by your mention of regex I found that this: `s2.apply(lambda x: re.split(':\d{1,3},?\s?',x))` was SUPER close. I'm not very familiar with regex so that's just somethign I hacked together. I'm getting an empty list item at the end because of the last `:\d\d` pattern - which I don't know how to get rid of via regex.

Comment: @dbyte oh I see, I'd missed the : bit. Do the regex replace *first*: `s2.str.replace(':\d+', '').str.split("\s*,\s*")`.

Comment: perfect! although the data was structured as `(",\s*")`. Awesome possum.

Comment: @dbyte the star means "0 or more" (so it doesn't care) :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your DataFrame

```
>>> df
                                 A
0  AB1234:12, CD5678:34, EF3456:56
1             AB1234:12, CD5678:34
2                             None
3             GH5678:34, EF3456:56
4                          OH56:34
```

And now I use `split` and `replace` to split by `', '` and remove all `':'`

```
>>> df.A = [i.replace(':','').split(", ") if isinstance(i,str) else i for i in df.A]
>>> df.A
0    [AB123412, CD567834, EF345656]
1              [AB123412, CD567834]
2                              None
3              [GH567834, EF345656]
4                          [OH5634]
Name: A
```

Comment: Apologies - i was, indeed, using commas - I just edited the question. I managed to reach to that point and am looking at how to delineate those lists by `":"`s. Then remove the second item in those embedded lists, however that portion is easily manageable and not in the scope of the question.

Comment: updated my answer. Hopefully that is what you were looking for!

Comment: almost! I wasn't clear and needed to get rid of the numbers/score after the `:`. I was thinking that this would create a list or lists and could remove the second item of each embedded list - the scores. The regex route, however, seems to shortcut this.